# How to control what back button does in android kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to make the back button go back to the main screen as the default is it goes to the previous screen. This is what I've tried:

```
this.onBackPressed{
     startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
}
```

However, I get an error. How do I implement this?

Comment: post your error here also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

override the onBackPressed method in your activity and try.

**replace your code with**

```
 override fun onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
    }
```